# C++ dynamic memory leaks

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-leaks

So I have this question, I'm currently learning how to get dynamic memory to allocate variables in the heap (on C++), so I just create a struct and put some items on it, then in the deleteList(estructura *) function i delete all variables, the problem is that I'm getting huge amounts of memory allocated, hence leaks.

```
    struct estructura
{
    char *algo;
    double *algo2;
    estructura *next;
};

estructura* lastEstructura(estructura *head)
{
    estructura *current = head;
    while (current -> next)
    {
        current = current -> next;
    }
    return current;
}

void crearLista(estructura *head)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8200; i++)
    {
        estructura *current = new estructura;
        current -> algo = new char[100];
        current -> algo2 = new double;
        current -> next = nullptr;
        estructura *temp = lastEstructura(head);
        temp -> next = current;
    }
}

void deleteList(estructura *head)
{
    estructura *current = head;
    while (current) {
        estructura *temp = current;
        current = current -> next;
        delete [] temp -> algo;
        delete temp -> algo2;
        temp -> next = nullptr;
        delete temp;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    cout << "enter: ";
    cin >> i;
    do {
        estructura *head = new estructura;
        head -> algo = new char[100];
        head -> algo2 = new double;
        head -> next = nullptr;
        crearLista(head);
        deleteList(head);
        cout << "enter: ";
        cin >> i;
    } while (i == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I really want to understand this, why do I get this leaks, so please somebody help me, I already tried searching and didn't find something that could help me.
(I'm relatively new to C++)

Comment: You can save your self a lot of headaches by changing your program to use `std::string` instead of `char* algo` and similar. Also why are you allocating 8200 list elements with a loop?

Comment: Once you learn the standard library  (std::string, std::vector ...) you no longer need to do things the hard way. Of course by then you will not implement your own linked list and instead use the standard library for that as well. Also if you really need to use new std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr will free you from this problem as well.

Comment: Use the debugger/valgrind but don't ask here in 1st place.

Comment: How much is a "huge amount of memory"? I don't see anything here that actually looks like it can cause a leak.

Comment: In everything I read here, *why do you think you have a memory leak*? Your program using memory is normal. It's when it terminated without freeing everything it newed is when there is a leak. Has a tool told you this was a problem, or do you just suspect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem is that you're allocating the members of an allocated object. Your code will be simpler if you just had:

```
struct estructura
{
    char algo[100];
    double algo2;
    estructura *next;
};
```

That way, `new estructura` gives you the full structure that you need and then `delete current` is the only thing you need to do. Also if you add a new member to `estructura`, everything just works without you having to worry about adding another `new`/`delete` pair.

Comment: using std::string is better

Comment: So you mean that allocating members of an allocated object, besides of not being recommended, would represent a leak? this is the part that I don't get very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You delete structure fields but you do forget to delete the structure instance. And also, you create a list very inefficiently. You do it in O(n^2) when it can be done in O(n).

Comment: Yes, I know, it's just a brief summary of the idea, the idea here is not to optimise but my doubt about the memory leak. Thanks, though.